# How to remove substrings "- " from a string in python, but keeping " - " substring?

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, nlp, str-replace

Example:

```
string = " a lot of text ... protective equip- ment ... a lot of text - with similar broken words like simple appli- cations ..."
```

I need to get the same text but *equip- ment* to became *equipment*, and *appli- cations* to became *applications*.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex that requires a hyphen followed by space, but rejects it if it's preceded by a space, will do the trick:

```
import re
string = "a lot of text ... protective equip- ment ... a lot of text - with similar broken words like simple appli- cations ..."
print(re.sub(r"(?<! )- ", "", string))
```

which outputs:

```
a lot of text ... protective equipment ... a lot of text - with similar broken words like simple applications ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex if you want to remove `'- '` between 2 words:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = " a lot of text ... protective equip- ment ... a lot of text - with similar broken words like simple appli- cations ..."
>>> re.sub(r"(\w+)- (\w+)", r"\1\2", string)
' a lot of text ... protective equipment ... a lot of text - with similar broken words like simple applications ...'
```

Comment: Can I know why am I downvoted? What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: It would be more helpful if the answer contained an explanation of what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: You don’t need to wait until next time, you can still edit this answer.

Comment: OK, I hope it's better now.

Comment: @Asocia, thanks. I'll try it, both solutions. In this post I just want to let you know that there are many many frustrated people in the world. They “cure” their frustrations, complexes, and problems that they can’t or don’t know how to solve in real life by downwoting anyone who doesn’t fit into their small, closed, and limited box. I used to be shocked with downwotes, but now I don't care. I knew in advance that they would downwot me, but I have no will to follow their limited and stupid rules of thought.